# How to merge all folders in one directory without merging their subfolders?

Tags: directory, merge

I have folders arranged as such:

```
Directory
-Subdirectory A 1
--Subdirectory B 1
--Subdirectory B 2
-Subdirectory A 2
--Subdirectory B 3
--Subdirectory B 4
```

How do I merge all the Subdirectory As into one folder without also merging the Subdirectory Bs?

Comment: What if A1 and A2 both have a B5?

Comment: In this case I know they do not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the output of

```bash
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort
```

It will give you the A's, but not the B's.

Copy with:

```bash
$ cp -p $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)  /some/dest/dir/
```

If you ever need to be more selective,
you can always ask `grep` to post-process
the output of `find` with your favorite regex.
Or even use `-type d` to just pick out the directory names.

Comment: I get this message:

find: warning: you have specified the global option -depth after the argument -type, but global options are not positional, i.e., -depth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it.  Please specify global options before other arguments.

find: paths must precede expression: `1'

Comment: @eldomtom2, haha! Thank you for that diagnostic, my mistake, I only tested  "/usr/bin/find . -type f -depth 1" on MacOS (BSD). I confess I found the manpage entry a bit confusing but I forged on ahead: "_-depth  Always true; same as the non-portable -d option. ... -depth N ..._". I should have paid closer attention to "non-portable". The POSIX folks changed the spelling -- what I wanted was `-maxdepth`. I have revised the Answer text, so that it _also_ works correctly on Ubuntu.